# Android listview getView checkBox

Tags: android, listview

Something strange is happening, when I click a row in the list the corresponding checkbox is also selected. So everything is right, but the strange thing is that, automatically every 7 rows the checkbox setcheked to true.
What's the problem? Thanks for your help

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio1>
            (this, R.layout.deteails_list_pdf, R.id.tv_nome_categoria, dettagli1) {
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
...
...
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final Dettaglio1 d1 = dettagli1.get(position);

                    d1.setChecked(!d1.isChecked());

                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
                    checkBox.setChecked(d1.isChecked());

                }
            });
            return row;
        }
    };
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
private class Dettaglio1 {
    String nome;

    private boolean isChecked;

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is known as *view recycling* - the core mechanism behind `ListView` and `RecyclerView`. Every 7th `CheckBox` is checked, because that's the same `CheckBox` recycled and displayed with its previous state.

To fix your problem, you need to keep the 'checked' state inside your data model (the `Dettaglio1` class). For example, you can modify your data model like so:

```
public class Dettaglio1 {
    // stuff
    private boolean isChecked;

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public void isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }
    // more stuff
}
```

And your listener like so:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Dettaglio1 d1 = dettagli1.get(position);
    d1.setChecked(!d1.isChecked());

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox.setChecked(d1.isChecked());
}
```

**Edit:**
You also need to override your adapter's `getView()` method and set the `CheckBox`'s checked state according to the `Dettaglio1` at the current position.

Comment: this solution does not solve the problem. I edited my post